# Any opensource Javascript editor/javascript eclipse plugin with code assist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just happened to read [jQuery Intellisense Updates from Microsoft](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/536756.aspx) and was wondering if there was any editor or eclipse plugin available which provides intellisense complete or code assist. Are there any?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe eclipse, with the **[Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/)** plugin, has some [JQuery support](http://www.aptana.com/blog/lorihc/jquery1.2.6_now_available).

As mentionned [here](http://www.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Getting_started_with_Aptana_and_jQuery), intellisense is supported:

> 5. Start coding.
>
> 1. As you type, notice that Code Assist is now active for the jQuery objects and functions that you use.
> 2. Press ctrl+space at any time to activate Code Assist.

Answer (score 2):

Why not Visual Studio/Web Developer 2008 (or did I miss something)? The [express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/) is free.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standalone version of [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/studio/download), it's free and much lighter than the complete Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Aptana provide Javascript code assist, but not intellisense. 
True intellisense for Javascript currently provided only by three IDs:

- NetBeans (open source)
- IntelliJ Idea  (proprietary web development)
- MS Visual Studio (proprietary, free edition exist)

So the answer - NetBeans.

But, unfortunately none of these do this job well.