# Plugin with javascript intellisense and autocomplete support?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, ide

I know this question has been asked previously, but they were asked a long time ago and answers to those questions weren't satisfactory. So I am asking it again - what is the best eclipse plugin available out there that can provide basic javascript as well as jquery auto-completion and intellisense if possible. I am looking for something other than Aptana Studio here.

I am using eclipse for J2EE developers version 3.6 Helios package (probably it has WTP installed from the start).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In term of pure auto-completion, bugs like [159508](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=159508), [121871](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=121871) or [125088](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=125088) seem to suggests it already exists, even though it doesn't have all the options of a [Visual Studio IntelliSense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

However, a more complete version of [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) was [available with Aptana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301036/any-opensource-javascript-editor-javascript-eclipse-plugin-with-code-assist/301050#301050) (as I reported in 2008), was still the best (in Eclipse world) [in 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925219/best-javascript-editor-ide-with-intellisense-and-debuggingpossibly/925250#925250), and can be installed as a plugin in an Eclipse (using the p2 update site http://update.aptana.com/install/studio):

See blog post [jQuery IntelliSense (code assists) on Eclipse 3.5](http://acaries.com/2010/07/jquery-intellisense-code-assists-on-eclipse-3-5/#post_content) (late 2010).

[image: Customize Aptana Studio]

Comment: Aptana makes my eclipse slow, very slow :(

Comment: @Sayem: did you try with an optimized `eclipse.ini`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659 (and see if the problem persists)

Comment: Since I am new to eclipse IDE, I couldn't make any heads and tails of your answer, but I will certainly try.

Comment: @Sayem: the gist if it is simply to replace the `eclipse.ini` with the one I mentioned above (adapting the path of your JDK in it). I am interested to know if it can improve the performances in your case ;)

Comment: I forgot that I was running Eclipse on VM :-( . Anyway, it doesn't really makes my Eclipse slow and the auto-complete is working nicely. I am still afraid to use your settings because I think it may interfere with my plugin installations (I think after installing Aptana there are some extra content added in this file), so didn't try that :-(. But thank you very very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest the WTP - does it lack the features you need?  It usually works pretty well for basic Javascript.

Comment: Yes, it has auto-completion for javascript, but no intellisense :( (like the small popup which opens describing what a function does when you type its name in visual studio). Also I can't figure out how to configure it to include jquery auto-completion.

Comment: I tried this previously - http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jquerywtp but didn't have much luck.  I used it quite a while ago, it may have improved.  As for the Intellisense functionality... I don't think you'll find a solution that is exactly what you're looking for.